# Calculating rewards with a negative binomial using expect() in scipy

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, expected-value, negative-binomial-distribution, scipy

I'm trying to model the rewards for a certain game. In that game, you pay 750 of the currency to enter, you play until you lose 3 times or win 7 times, and then you get a reward equal to the number of wins you got.

For this reason I've modelled the number of wins as `nbinom`. Each "success" in the Bernoulli trial refers to losing a game, so we stop after 3 successes, and each "failure" refers to winning a game, so the number of failures tells us what reward the player should get.

As it stands, my current function takes a win rate and returns the expected value:

```
from scipy.stats import nbinom

def ev(win_rate):
    # 0 wins gives you a reward of 50, 7 wins gets you a reward of 950
    rewards = [50, 100, 200, 300, 450, 650, 850, 950]

    # `games` counts the number of wins until we get 3 losses
    # We want the probability of losing here, not winning, so we invert the win_rate
    games = nbinom(n=3, p=1 - win_rate)

    ev = games.expect(
        ub=7, # We can only win at most 7 games
        func=lambda x: rewards # The number of Bernoulli "failures" (wins) determines the reward
    )
    cost = 750
    return ev - cost
```

However, the values it actually returns are wacky. I get:

```py
for i in (0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1):
    print('{}: {}'.format(i, ev(i)))
```

```
0: -700.0
0.2: -648.04597248
0.4: -529.65967872
0.6: -409.9028531199999
0.8: -564.05664768
1: -750.0
```

But I know that, if your win rate is 1, you should always be obtaining the reward of 950, meaning an `ev()` of positive `250`. But somehow the function is returning `-750` for this case.

Why is this happening? Am I modelling this incorrectly? Or is it a bug in the code somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour of testing I finally figured it out. It seems that the argument `ub=7` means you're stopping the integration at 7, and that means that if you get more than 7 wins then it doesn't calculate it and basically the reward is 0.

thus, right after you calculate `ev` you should add to it the probability of getting more than 7 wins times the reward for all those possible number of wins (in our case its a constant 950). Thus just do:

```
ev += (1 - games.cdf(7))*rewards[-1]
```

I hope this helps, I was also getting frustrated trying to debug this one.

EDIT:
Here's a way to try to make the `expect` method to handle this by itself (just make sure not to pass `p=1` cause that will make it return 0

```
def ev(win_rate):
    # 0 wins gives you a reward of 50, 7 wins gets you a reward of 950

    rewards = [50, 100, 200, 300, 450, 650, 850, 950]
    map_rewards = lambda index: rewards[index] if index < len(rewards) else rewards[-1]
    def reward_func(x):
        x = x.astype(np.int)
        return np.array(list(map(map_rewards, x)))

    # `games` counts the number of wins until we get 3 losses
    # We want the probability of losing here, not winning, so we invert the win_rate
    games = nbinom(n=3, p=1 - win_rate)
    ev = games.expect(
        ub=1e5,
        func=reward_func # The number of Bernoulli "failures" (wins) determines the reward
    )
    cost = 750
    return ev - cost

for i in (0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.967): # anything larger than .967 will break
    print('{}: {}'.format(i, ev(i)))
```

Comment: Oh, of course! I was trying to emulate `wins = min(games, 7)` using `ub`, but I can now see why that doesn't work.

Comment: Pity there isn't a neater way for the `expect()` function to handle this automatically, though.

Comment: If you're interested, I just added a way to try to make the `expect()` method handle it by itself... Kind of.